# Random process with very high rate of convergence

Tags: probability, random-walk

Write down a sequence of random (positive, whole) numbers which are not very large (say within a factor of ten or so) compared to its length.  Start anywhere not very far from the end of the sequence (say within the first half or so). Walk as many numbers down the line as there are units contained in the number you are currently in. Do this repeatedly until you can no longer do so without extrapolating the sequence. I will then say you are at your final destination. Then, for almost all such sequences and almost all initial positions, the final destination is a constant which depends only on the sequence, but not on the initial position. (In a sense I cannot define precisely but if you do the experiment with concrete numbers, you will see that the probabilities are astoundingly high).

Does anyone know the name of this phenomenon?
Does anyone know an explanation for it?

Thank you for your answer(s).

Comment: Could you give a numerical example of such a sequence and walk?

Comment: Explanation: Run the walk for two different starting points. Each time walk 1 is ahead, freeze it and run walk 2 until it overcomes walk 1. Walk 2 has a nonzero probability to pass by the position occupied by walk 1. If walk 2 overcomes walk 1 without meeting it, restart with walk 2 freezed and walk 1 moving forward. Note that, once walks 1 and 2 are at a same position once, they stay together till the end. Thus the probability that they are still not together after $n$ steps decreases geometrically with $n$. QED.

Comment: Yes, here it is: 3, 5, 6, 7, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3, 3, 2, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 1, 7, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 2, 8, 3, 2, 5, 8, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 8, 2, 4, 5, 5, 1, 6

For example, starting at the initial 3 the sequence of steps would be: 3, 7,  2, 5, 3, 7, 4, 4, 1, 3, 5, 3, 8, 4, 6

If you start about anywhere else the sequences of paths will start to converge at some point, and you will end at the same 6, with very few exceptions.

Comment: @Did I am amazed at how something so mindblowing can have such a tautologically simple explanation!

Comment: This is probably developed as an example of the effectiveness of *coupling from the past* in some introductory texts on this subject.

Comment: "Coupling from the past"! Now I have a keyword to search for! Thank you very much.